# Storing JSON data in database: object could not be converted to string error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

In a nut shell, I have my data in Javascript:

```
JSONdata = {
    name: form.name.value,
    address1: form.custa.value,
    address2: form.custa2.value,
    postcode: form.custpc.value,
    order: fullorder,
    cost: document.getElementById('total')
  }
```

**fullorder** is an array of products to be ordered. :
`[{"idnum":"2","cost":232,"quantity":"1"},{"idnum":"1","cost":2342,"quantity":"3"}]`

I have an XJAX which stringifies this data as seen below:

```
{"name":"j","address1":"jh","address2":"jhj","postcode":"h","order":[{"idnum":"2","cost":232,"quantity":"1"},{"idnum":"1","cost":2342,"quantity":"3"}],"cost":{}}
```

In PHP it's given as an array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [idnum] => 2
            [cost] => 232
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [idnum] => 1
            [cost] => 2342
            [quantity] => 3
        )

)
```

My question is how to store this in an database?
I've tried serialize and  json_encode but both give me a:
"Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-> Don't worry about querying the database and the JSON battle.
I will be getting all data out at once so it's not an issue :)

**EDIT:** Thanks for the replies guys, I give you some info about how it works:

So when I send the JSON to my PHP, I have a script which extracts all the data out like so:

```
$intel = extractdata();
function extractdata() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])){
    $jsonDump = json_decode($_REQUEST['data']);
  foreach($jsonDump as $key => $value) {
    $obj[$key] = $value;
  }
  return $obj;
}
```

So this gives me

```
$intel['name'] = // form.name.value variable
$intel['address1'] = // form.name.value variable
```

And `$intel['order']` gives me the PHP array seen above. I want to store all this in to a database in the columns: Customername, address1, address2, postcode, order, cost

I thought by just `$neworder = json_encode($intel['order'])` would allow me to store it in a database but it still throws the convertion error.

Thanks

Comment: Normalize your database and store it in multiple columns.

Comment: So, what line of code is actually throwing that error?
It's great that you've shown us the data (_no sarcasm_), but that's only part of the application ;-)

Comment: @N.B.: No need to be condescending.

Comment: Tagged as PHP, but no PHP code present. Clearly an issue of trying to store the PHP data-structure to the database, rather than the existing string-form (received via HTTP, already JSON serialised).

Comment: @Cerbrus - I'm not, nor am I trying to insult, the person in question is **obviously** capable, but he just can't see the forest from the trees.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have an array that contains an object like this:

```
$o = array((Object)array(array("idnum"=>2, "cost"=>232, "quantity"=>1), array("idnum"=>1, "cost"=>2342, "quantity"=>3)));
```

Echoing this with `json_encode()` will return a json string:

```
echo json_encode($o);
```

and the result will be

```
[
  {
    "0": {
      "idnum": 2,
      "cost": 232,
      "quantity": 1
    },
    "1": {
      "idnum": 1,
      "cost": 2342,
      "quantity": 3
    }
  }
]
```

isn't this working for you? Also are you using any framework or just pure php?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated my question to better reflect what I'm asking, just using pure PHP!

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:

```
$jsonDump = json_decode($_REQUEST['data']);
```

I believe you dont need this:

```
  foreach($jsonDump as $key => $value) {
    $obj[$key] = $value;
  }
```

moreover, you don't initiate $obj (should be $obj = null at the beggining of the function or sth.).

What you need is `json_encode((array) $obj);` to convert the object to a simple array before stringifying, this should solve your problem. You can also implement a `_toSting($obj)` function like:

```
  $str = '{';
  foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
    $str .= '"'.$key.'":"'.$value.'"';
    $str .= ',';
  }
  $str = trim(',',$str).'}';
```

Comment: Your "`toString`" function will not work for objects that contain arrays, objects, or other complex types.

Comment: true, I meant just a simple example, we could add recurrence in
$str .= '"'.$key.'":"'.toString($value).'"';

Comment: You mean "Recursion". But why would you write your own version of `json_encode`?

Comment: I do mean recursion, its just an example of the solution @Cerbrus, to show another option for the person asking.